# I need to send an 8-byte string to an SNMP agent, but it's receiving the wrong values

Tags: java, snmp

I need to send an 8-byte string to an SNMP agent.

My number can be a big integer as a string.
Due to the java limitation of signed bytes, I'm having a problem with some numbers.

For example, if num is "555", the SNMP agent receives the right value.
if num is "666", the SNMP agent receives the wrong value, because, one of the byte in the 
array has a -ve value.

I did a bit & with 0xFF, still it doesn't work.
How can I fix this? Thanks for your help!

```
 public static String stringNumToOctetString(String num) {
    BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(num);
    byte[] b = bi.toByteArray();

    int n = 8 - b.length;
    byte[] bVal = new byte[8]; //return must be 8 bytes
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++) {
        bVal[i] = (byte) 0;
    }
    int k = 0;
    for(int j=n; j<8; j++) {
        bVal[j] = (byte) (b[k++] & 0xFF);
    }
    return new String(bVal);
}
```

Comment: What is a `-ve` value?  Are you saying "negative" value?  `byte` doesn't hold negative values.  Is this Java?

Comment: This is in Java. Yes, "negative" value. In this case, one of the byte in b[] has it.

Comment: OK.  What about the rest of my questions?  Specifically, how is what you're doing causing SNMP to explode?  Please be more specific.

Comment: See the line, `byte[] b = bi.toByteArray();` As explained in the example, if I pass "666", the `b[0]` has 2 and `b[1]` has -102 . If I pass "555" as a parameter, the `b[0]` has 2 and `b[1]` has 43.

Comment: Gotcha.  See, this is why the `byte` in java sucks; it's a *signed* number.  It has a range of -128 to +127, so you're not gonna get the values you want.

Comment: Why don't you just use an array of `int` instead of an array of `byte` to store the octet values.  That way, you won't have problems with negative overflow anymore.

Comment: See also http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=13647

Comment: b[0] shoul be 2 b[1] should be 154

Comment: Right, and 154 exceeds the range of a `byte`, which is why you're getting negative overflow.  Use an array of `int` to store your values.

Answer (score 1):

Use an array of `int` to store your octet values, not an array of `byte`.  `byte` is signed, and has a range of -128 to +127, so it's not going to work here, where you need values to go to 255.

**Further Reading**
http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=13647